# Joomla 3 custom plugin installation: add a folder with images from zip to images folder

Tags: plugins, joomla, components, joomla-component

My custom plugin needs add a folder with images in "images" folder of joomla. Is this possible and if yes how can i tell my install script to take this folder and copy it in images path?

Comment: do you really need images in "images" folder of Joomla or it may be media folder??

Comment: Look at the Joomla documentation for the File System Package. Everything you need to manipulate folders and files is there

Comment: Yes inside the images folder . Iknow how to put them in media folder from xml but i need them in images folder.

Comment: i checked the Joomla documentation for the File System Package, i know how to create ,file, folder etc. I need to take a folder with images from the zip and put them under images folder.( that is what i did not found )

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found a way to do it . In my xml file i added

```
<media folder="" destination="../images">
    <folder>testfolder</folder>

</media>
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issues being how to include an archive file with your installation package and then how to deal with zip files using exclusively PHP functionality to un-package and place where you want them.

EDIT

I made an error, the original link didn't contain the required information to create installation scripts to run during your extensions install.  The *new* second link is however specific to doing this.  I would recommend storing the images somewhere in you installation package, and manually moving them during installation to where you need them in the images folder using one of the available methods to hook into.

Sorry for the error, good luck!

http://docs.joomla.org/Package
[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)

Comment: i do not want to use zip . Is there another way ?

Comment: I made an error in my original post, use the new second link to manually move the images where you need them.  Just remember when writing code inside the context of the installer class, you are not dealing with archived files, as far as the code is concerned you are dealing with files structure set by the extension manifest file.